# How to reset form values after closing?

Tags: c#, webforms

I have a Login form that users use to log in. After logging in, they will be presented with another form, and this form contains different labels. Each label is being treated as a button. The form is divided into 2 panels, the left panel is for the labels, and the right panel is for the button action. For example, I have 3 labels on the left side one called "Home" and the other one is "Register User" and lastly "Log Out" when I press the label "Users" a TabControl will be showing on the right side and it has 2 tabs "Register user" And "Current Users".

After I click on "Log Out" and I log in with a different user I want everything to be clean just like if I was opening it from the beginning. For example, the Home page should show first and not the last visible panel. If I log in with user called "test" now and I click on "Users" and then log out and log in from a different user I will still see The "Users" panel open and every value entered in textboxes is still open. And I don't want this.

The code I used to log out is:

```
private void LogOutBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
        Globals.LoginForm.Show();
    }
```

The code I use to move from the login form to the welcome form is:

```
 private void LoginBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                    this.Hide();
                    Globals.WelcomeForm.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never Mind I got it working. I know my mistake :) declaring it in a different class and calling from that class was causing me this problem.

My code now is

```
private void LoginBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Welcome NewWelcomeForm = new Welcome();
     his.Hide();
     NewWelcomeForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring a new WelcomeForm each you show it.  Something like this:

```
 private void LoginBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         Globals.WelcomeForm NewWelcomeForm = new Globals.WelcomeForm();
         this.Hide();
         NewWelcomeForm.ShowDialog();
    }
```

The new constructor will reset all the controls and their values.

Comment: It doesn't allow me to do so because "Globals" is a class that I created and inside that class I have declared a new WelcomeForm.
Here is my Globals Code                                                                         public static Login LoginForm = new Login();
       public static Welcome WelcomeForm = new Welcome();

Comment: Try `Globals.Welcome NewWelcomeForm = new Globals.Welcome();`

Answer (score 0):

How C # will be able to release old information to a new tab in the form.For example, we have registered it saved data when we enter it in the login it opens a new tab and when it opens it releases the information in the registration

Comment: Your answer could be improved by with additional supporting information. This question has already been answered with more high value answers so it would be great if you could highlight how your answer differentiate. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).